# PhpUnit: Run all tests which are NOT in a testsuite?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, test-suite

Is it possible to filter all tests which are not part of the defined test suites?

We have already defined some test suites but it may happen that sometimes tests will be written which are not covered by a testsuite...